# Magento 2 - not recieved test email in SMTP extension

Tags: email, magento2.3.1, smtp

We have installed Mageplaza SMTP extension in our magebto 2 store and configured the extension, But We are not able to receive emails. I have to below attached screen short.
[image]

Comment: Check if the port declared for smtp is used by any other services?

Comment: please share your configuration

Answer (score 0):

First check ports. I think your hosting/server is blocking port 25, 465, or 587.

Check this url  : https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/issues/97

Second : Flush your storage and caches. Run these commands :

```
php bin/magento c:f

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php -dmemory=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

My problem solved with these steps in past.